# Microsoft word text field referencing

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to reference text fields using Microsoft Word 2010. I am writing terms and conditions forms, so my first page is something like that:

```
company name: [textfield]
contact person: xxx
phone: xxx
```

So I want to use the details I entered on the first page updated on the next pages, for example, 2nd page contains:

```
I [company_name] accept terms and conditions etc...

[contact_person]
[phone]
```

For example, here is the text

So I want to enter company name 1 time, so it should appear in the next text forms.

So the final result should be like this:

```
Company: test

I test accept terms and conditions above.
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

- Add Bookmarks to a Word template that you save;
- Apply the following code:

```
    Dim sSave_Path                              As String  
    Dim sSave_File                              As String  
    Dim sFile_Template                          As String  

    Dim oWord_App                               As Word.Application  
    Dim oWord_Doc                               As Word.Document

    sFile_Template = "" 'Define template File  
    sSave_Path = "" 'Define Save Path  
    sSave_File = "" 'Define Save Filename  

    Set oWord_App = New Word.Application  
    Set oWord_Doc = oWord_App.Documents.Add(sFile_Template)  
    oWord_App.Visible = True
    oWord_App.Activate

    oWord_Doc.Bookmarks("TEST").Range.Text = "TEST"
    oWord_Doc.SaveAs sSave_Path & "\" & sSave_File & ".doc"
    oWord_Doc.Close
    oWord_App.Quit
```

Comment: I got the idea. but my question was how can i pass text field by referece, I would like to enter company name once, while the others field where i will reference &company_name will be changes also

Comment: I'm not certain if I get it right. However, I think that you always need to either push the information from Excel to Word, or pull it out of Excel from a Word Doc. Of course, you can use events to do this automatically (such as when updating a cell or textbox as you mentioned). I assume you are working from Excel because of the tags. If you are purely working in Word, best is that you update the tags.

Comment: I am using word, yes you got me right, I want to update my textfieds with the same value what i entered in the first text field

Comment: Hm, sorry but now you got me confused... You are using textboxes in Word or Excel? "I want to update my textfieds with the same value what i entered in the first text field" Do I understand from this that you input data into a textbox in Word and need an output in another textfield in the same Word file? Then why the Excel tags? Thanks for elaborating.

Comment: I thought the idea will be the same since the VBA is used for word and excel. However, I hope you got my point, I am writing an termsn and conditions agreement, so the details i entered at the first page must be updated in the following next text fields

Comment: Based on your last input, in that case the answer of ForEachLoop seems correct. If you update the Company name once in the standard Properties of the document, the Quickparts fields will be upated automatically throughout the document.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide more information, or code you tried, better answers can be given. There’s several ways to go about this but one is simple: Insert|QuickParts|Field|DocProperty|Company. This inserts the value of the document property as saved by Word in File|Info|Properties (Show All Properties).